# How to name the different type of percentages in a table?

Tags: percentage

The terms *column percent* and *row percent* are quite self describing.

With *column percent* here in this example each sum for `GroupA` and `GroupB` is 100%.

```
|         | GroupA   | GroupB   |
|:--------|:---------|:---------|
| Sex     | -        | -        |
|  female | 45       | 40       |
|  male   | 55       | 60       |
             |          |
             V          V
           100%       100%
```

With *row percent* here in this example each sum for `female` and `male` is 100%.

```
|         | GroupA   | GroupB   |
|:--------|:---------|:---------|
| Sex     | -        | -        |
|  female | 45       | 55       |  --> 100%
|  male   | 55       | 45       |  --> 100%
```

But how do you name it here? What type of *percent* are shown here? Here the data is stratified in two (?) dimensions: The group's (`GroupA` and `GroupB`) and the strata `Sex` and `Age`.

```
|         | GroupA   | GroupB   |
|:--------|:---------|:---------|
| Sex     | -        | -        |
|  female | 45       | 40       |
|  male   | 55       | 60       |
| Age     | -        | -        |
|  young  | 20       | 30       |
|  old    | 80       | 70       |
```

It could be named sub-column or strata-percent? Is there an official terminology for it that could be used in a peer-reviewed publication?

Comment: Your third (and first) table show percentages with each group

Comment: How would you write that in a table footnote? _group percent_? _percent for each group_? _percent per group_? ...?

Comment: I would write in the table name "Percentages within each group" (sorry for missing -in earlier)

Comment: @Henry, that works well with groups named “GroupA” and “GroupB”. If the groups are referred to as treated and control, then “per group” might need some clarification

Comment: The bottom display *still* shows column percentages *by panel.*  After all, it's not doing anything more complicated or different: it's merely displaying two separate $2\times 2$ tables, one for `Sex` and `Group` and the other for `Age` and `Group`.  It is erroneous to refer to these as "strata," because that term ordinarily means the panels are *mutually disjoint,* but they evidently are not.